# About the rank of sets

Tags: set-theory

Let us work in ZFC set theory, let A and B be two sets and C be the set of functions with domain A and range B.
Question: what can be said about c=rank(C), knowing a=rank(A) and b=rank(B) ?
Gérard Lang

Comment: Kunen, chapter III, exercise 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every function $f$ is a subset of $A\times B$, and so the rank of $C$ is at most $\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}\rank(\mathcal P(A\times B))$.

It is possible that $\rank(A\times B)=\rank(A)=\rank(B)$. For example in the case $A=B=\omega$. But it is possible that $\rank(A\times B)>\rank(A),\rank(B)$. For example where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets.

More generally if $\max\{\rank(A),\rank(B)\}$ is a limit ordinal then you can show that $A\times B$ will have the same rank as that maximum, otherwise it will have a strictly larger rank.

To be on the safe side, you can always show that $\rank{A^B}\geq\max\{\rank(A),\rank(B)\}+3$.

Comment: If you use a flat pairing function (and your sets have infinite rank), you can reduce the $+3$ to $+1$, since in that case pairs do not increase rank. The $+3$ arises from the Kuratowski pairing function, which increases rank by $2$, but there are other pairing function that do not do this.

Comment: True, Joel. Thank you for pointing that out. It's one of the places where the choice of encoding the pairs matters.

Comment: Another ranking function which will accomplish what Joel's describes is Quine's pairing function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition